# How to add new column to exitsting table symfony - orocommerce

Tags: symfony, orocommerce

I'm working on an **orocommerce** project, and it use vendor/oro/bundles/bundle_name
And in that bundle, it have an entity named "**oro_customer_user**", so i want to add a  new column in that table using my new bundles.
I've searched a lot but still no luck.
Almost of solution say i need to fix in **vendor**/oro/bundles/bundle_name, which i don't want to do.
But still have some solution say i need to use **DoctrineMigrationsBundle** but i'm not sure about this.
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Please give advice, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so i've found the solution for **orocommerce** 
Just use **Migration** and everything is gonna be fine
You can check in this link:
https://forum.oroinc.com/orocrm/orocrm-programming-questions/topic/add-custom-field-into-orocrm-entity#post-24765 
The migrate you have to create manual, because i don't know how to create migrate by command line :( .
After create migrate done, you only need to run this cmd:

```
php app/console oro:migration:load --show-queries
```

Now go and check in database, its done already.

---

And about entity:

I still don't know how to custom it in orocommerce. It got a lot of error.